# Navbar sticky on some pages but no others

Tags: css

I am using the same navbar for every pages of my website: http://asia-hr.com

**The logo is just different on the home page but that's the only difference**

The navbar is sticky on the home page but not on every other pages despises to have the same css properties for the #navbar on every pages.

Do you know what can be the issue?

/* NavBar */

```
#navbar{
    z-index: 100000;
    background:#34495e;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    padding:1rem;
}
```

Comment: Home page don't have `<div id="header">` try to change `position: sticky;` to `position: sticky !important;`.

Comment: **Don't abuse `!important`.**

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

The problem is simple. `position: sticky` is depended on its parent.
Since in your home page your `#navbar` is a child of `body`, it will stick to `body`.
But in other pages, your `#navbar` is a child of `#header`, and `#header` has only `#navbar` which results in the same height of the navbar, so it's not sticky anymore.

You can fix this issue in two ways:

1. Extract `#navbar` from `#header` so it would be the child of `body`.
2. change `position: sticky` to `position: fixed` since in your case, it's the same thing.